# Design pattern for directed acyclic graphs in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-design, nosql

#### The problem

As usual the problem is to display a [directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) in a database. The choices for a Database I had were a relational database like *mysql* or *mongodb*. I chose mongoDb because DAGs in relational databases are [a mess](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22824/A-Model-to-Represent-Directed-Acyclic-Graphs-DAG-o) but if there is a trick I just didn't find please tell me.

The goal is to map a DAG in one or multiple MongoDB Documents. Because we have multiple children **and** parents *SubDocuments* where no possibility. I came across multiple design patterns but am not sure which one is the best to go with.

---

#### Tree-structure with Ancestors Array

The Ancestors Array is [suggested by the mongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-ancestors-array/). And is quite easy to understand. As I understand it my document would look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "root",
    "ancestors" : [ null ],
    "left": 1
}
{
    "_id" : "child1",
    "ancestors" : [ "root" ],
    "left": 2
}
{
    "_id" : "child2",
    "ancestors" : [ "root", "child1" ],
    "left": 1
}
```

This allows me to `find` all children of an element like this:

```
db.Tree.find({ancestors: 'root'}).sort({left: -1})
```

and all parents like this:

```
db.Tree.findOne({_id: 'child1'}).ancestors
```

#### DBRefs instead of Strings

My second approach would be to replace the **string-keys** with  `DBRef`s. But except for longer *database records* I don't see many advantages over the **ancestors array**.

#### String-based array with `children` and `parents`

The last idea is to store not only the `children` of each document but it's `parents` as well. This would give me all the features I want. The downside is the massive overhead of information I would create by storing all *relations* two times. Further on I am worried by the amount of administration there is. E.g. if a document gets deleted I have to check all others for a reference in multiple fields.

---

#### My Questions

- Is MongoDb the right choice over a relational database for this purpose?
- Are there any up-/downsides of any of my pattern I missed?
- Which pattern would you suggest and why? Do you maybe have experience with one of them?

Comment: Why aren't you using a graph database? If you store nodes as documents with references, it's not much different from a RDBMS solution.

Comment: I am using doctrine as an abstraction layer. The support for other Databases is not that well or non-existent. So I am limited to mongoDB or *SQL.

Comment: @ferdynator could you explain the meaning\usage of the left property? I'm working on a similar problem where child nodes can have multiple *direct* parents so it's a DAG and not a tree.

Comment: @DanielS it is used for sorting of parents/children. In my case order was relevant and I needed to be able to rearrange items on the same level. If you don't care about that you can skip it.

Comment: @ferdynator is that how you defined levels? any node on the same level would have  same 'left' value?

Comment: @DanielS no levels are defined by the ancestor property. all items on one level have the same ancestor but different left values.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a graph database? Check ArangoDB, you can use documents like MongoDB and also graphs. MongoDB is a great database, but not for storing graph oriented documents. ArangoDB does.

https://www.arangodb.com/